# Send-only address in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a problem with setting up a send-only account in Outlook 2013 - more specifically..

Here's what I have working:
I have an outlook.com account where I've set up a send-only gmail account. That is on web (outlook.com). When I send an email from the web client, I can choose to send it via the specified gmail account. The email is sent correctly and the message shows up in the Sent folder in outlook.This is the way I WANT it to work.

Now here's the problem:
When I add my outlook account into Outlook 2013, I can not send an email via my gmail account (not surprisingly). So I added my gmail account as well and disabled receiving emails for the gmail account. At this point, I am able to send emails via gmail, but obviously - the message shows up in the Sent folder in gmail, not outlook.

Is there a way to achieve the same setup in Outlook 2013 as is the case in the outlook.com web client?

Comment: This is simply because Outlook emails work better with `Outlook 2013` than Google Mail does although there are plugins that make its integration better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Outlook 2013 rule which triggers when sending emails. Set it to make a copy of the sent mail to your outlook's sent item folder. This rule will be a local-machine only rule because its behaviour is having to do with multiple mailboxes.

As for gmail's sent items, when you use gmail's service to send an email, it **will** be automatically recorded in gmail's sent items, including the emails you had sent with outlook.com. Only this time, it is synced automagically with your Outlook 2013's gmail mailbox thanks to IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the IMAP works. I believe you've managed to configure your Gmail account in Outlook as IMAP. This is why you see your sent emails in its Sent Items. If you want to use another folder for sent messages, you may want to add the PST file and make it the primary storage. Another way is to add Gmail account as POP3.